Apache Beam: Number of components does not match number of coders when using Timers
My question is very similar to this one
I'm trying to add some timers to process some data later but i'm getting the following error
Error message from worker: generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1435, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 636, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1621, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler.handle_process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1734, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputHandler._write_value_to_tag
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 266, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonElementConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 528, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.process
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 158, in process
    self.windowed_coder_impl.encode_to_stream(
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1448, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1467, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1023, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.AbstractComponentCoderImpl.encode_to_stream
ValueError: Number of components does not match number of coders.

my Dofn
class WaitUntilDevicesExist(beam.DoFn):
    BUFFER_STATE = beam.transforms.userstate.BagStateSpec('buffer', beam.coders.StrUtf8Coder())
    TIMER = beam.transforms.userstate.TimerSpec('timer', beam.TimeDomain.REAL_TIME)

    BUFFER_TIMER = 15  # seconds

    ...

    def process(self, key_value, timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(TIMER), buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE)):
        shard_id, batch = key_value

        for message in batch:
            logging.info(f"Checking = {message}")
            
            ...

            if (...):
                timer.set(timestamp.Timestamp.now() + timestamp.Duration(seconds=self.BUFFER_TIMER)) 
                buffer.add(DeviceCheckHelper(message).to_string())
            else:
                yield message

    @beam.transforms.userstate.on_timer(TIMER)
    def expiry_callback(self, timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(TIMER), buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE)):
        events = buffer.read()
        logging.info("Timer")
        new_buffer = []

        for row in events:
            message = DeviceCheckHelper.from_string(row)
            logging.info(message)
            
            ....

            if (...):
                if retry == 3:
                    logging.info(f"Waited 3 times, yielding ")
                    yield message.message
                else:
                    message.increase_retry()
                    new_buffer.append(message.to_string())
                    logging.info(f"retry = {message}")

        buffer.clear()
        timer.clear()

        logging.info(f"New buffer = {new_buffer}")
        if new_buffer:
            for row in new_buffer:
                logging.info(f"Adding {row}")
                buffer.add(row)

            timer.set(timestamp.Timestamp.now() + timestamp.Duration(seconds=self.BUFFER_TIMER))

and the pipeline looks like this
# 1 filter messages
filtered_messages = (
    transformed_messages[TransformData.TAG_OK]
    | f"Clean Devices {tenant}" >> beam.ParDo(FilterMessages()).with_outputs(FilterMessages.DEVICE_TAG, FilterMessages.OBSERVATION_TAG)
)

# 2 Write observations

    observation_results = (
        filtered_messages[FilterMessages.OBSERVATION_TAG]
        | f"{tenant} Check Devices" >> beam.ParDo(WaitUntilDevicesExist(...))
        | f"{tenant} Window Observations messages" >> GroupMessagesByShardedKey(max_messages=200, max_waiting_time=10, shard_key="obs", num_shards=10)
        | f"{tenant} Write Observations" >> beam.ParDo(Write(...)).with_outputs(FAILED_TAG)
    
    )
    

If I move the WaitUntilDevicesExist after the GroupMessagesByShardedKey it works fine. What am I missing?

Its hard to say for sure without seeing the other DoFns here, but it looks to me like you're yielding unkeyed output from WaitUntilDevicesExist, and then calling a GroupByKey (or similar operation) in GroupMessagesByShardedKey. Instead of just yielding the message, should you be doing something like the following?
yield shard_id, message
I think Number of components does not match number of coders. is basically saying that the coders are expecting a key/value pair, and you're only passing them a value.
